# Executing and cacheing python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a program that opens IDLE and executes code typed into it, much like IDLE but tailored to my needs. I use this code to execute the commands and save it:

```
c = raw_input(indent)
allthecode.append(c + '\n')
atclen = len(allthecode) - 1
extremelyrandomvariablenamethatnoonewouldeverguess24 = c
exec(''.join(allthecode))
        if runtime == 'interactive':
            if 'print ' in extremelyrandomvariablenamethatnoonewouldeverguess24:
                actlen = len(allthecode) - 1
                allthecode[actlen] = ''
        if 'help()' in extremelyrandomvariablenamethatnoonewouldeverguess24:
            actlen = len(allthecode) - 1
            allthecode[actlen] = ''
```

It seems as if this works, and it's done the job so far, but I don't feel like this is the right way to do this. I've tried appending the code to a file and reading and executing/importing it, but executing didn't work quite right, and importing it screwed everything up. Is there anything I could do to save it correctly, and if not, what other things do I need to/not need to remove from code?

Thanks.

Comment: W...why wouldn't you just call `python name_of_file.py`???

Comment: @JackManey I'm not executing code, at least not here, I'm running code that has been typed into the 'Custom Idle'. using sub-processes runs a whole new file each time. The main issue is I need to be able to dynamically create variables in their own local environment, with its own globals and locals, and functions, and exec() won't let me do this for some reason.

Comment: I still don't understand why you couldn't just type into a file, save it, and then execute it the old-fashioned way.